# AspectJ: after returning not reached

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I've created this aspect:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.living.commty.boot.resources.*.* (..))")
public void resourcesCut() {}
```

I'm trying to get execution after they has been returned:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut="resourcesCut()", returning="result")
public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result)
{
    this.logAfterReturningTrace(joinPoint, result);
}
```

My class is:

```
package com.living.commty.boot.resources;
public class EmailResources {

    @Inject private ConfigurationResources configurationResources;
    @Inject protected TokenResources cipheringResources;

    public String buildURI(String id, byte[] token) throws URISyntaxException
    {       
        return "";
    }

    public byte[] decodeParameter(String value)
    {
        return "";
    }

    public void sendActivationMail(User user) throws MailGenerationException
    {

    }
}
```

However, they are never reached.

Nevertheless, if I add an `@Before`:

```
@Before("resourcesCut()")
public void beforeCreate(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    this.logBeforeTrace(joinPoint);
}
```

it's reached!

**ECLIPSE**

As you can see into this images:

1. `@AfterThrowing` wraps a lot of methods, up to 39, more or less.

[image]

2. But, `@AfterReturning` only wraps 6 method executions...

[image]

Comment: The pointcut is correct, the advice declaration is correct, so it might be your environment. Are you using AspectJ or Spring AOP?

Comment: I've added on post some images showing eclipse (AJDT) behavior. In short, `@AfterThrowing` wraps more methods than `@AfterReturning`... Any ideas?

Comment: Any difference between method signatures of those advised by, and those not advised by the after returning advice?

Comment: IMHO, I think that's not the problem. As far I've been to figure out, `@After(pointcut="resourcesCut"), @AfterReturning(pointcut="resourcesCut")`, and `@AfterThrowing(pointcut="resourcesCut")` should cut the same points. Nevertheless, `@After` and `@AfterThrowing` are cutting 39 points, but `@AfterReturning` is cutting only 6! Am I wrong?

Comment: I've just realized that if I write `@AfterReturning(pointcut="resourcesCut()")` without setting returning porperty, it reaches 39 pointcuts! If I write `@AfterReturning(pointcut="resourcesCut()", returning="result") public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result)`...

Comment: I've created a new post in order to ask for it on [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43676168/aspectj-afterreturning)