# AspectJ: @AfterReturning

Tags: aop, aspectj

I've created this pointcut:

```
@Pointcut("execution(* com.living.commty.boot.resources.*.* (..))")
public void resourcesCut() {}
```

I'm trying to get the return value after having been returned:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut="resourcesCut()", returning="result")
public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result)
{
    //...
}
```

The problem is that it's cutting only 6 advises. However, if I not set `returning`:

```
@AfterReturning(pointcut="resourcesCut()")
public void afterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint)
{
    this.logAfterReturningTrace(joinPoint, null);
}
```

it's cutting up to 39 advises.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to get all returned values of any "resourcesCut" pointcut execution methods...

Comment: Are you sure that those 33 missing join points aren't on exit of void-returning methods?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure! NEvertheless, void method are also wrapped by @AfterReturning as well, aren't it?

Comment: Yes, but I figured it may be because AJ couldn't bind "result" to anything in case of void methods. Can't help you if you're sure, that was just a quick idea.